Hibernate : could not interpret path expression when doing JOIN on unrelated tables
I have the tables: Post and UserSettings.
userId is coming from external DB that's why both entites are unrelated.
I am using hibernate 6.
The left join with comments is already working.
@Entity
data class Post(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,
    val userId: Long,  
    val content: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    val comments: List<Comment> = emptyList()
)

@Entity
data class UserSettings(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,
    val userId: Long,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // Ensure correct enum mapping
    val settings: Setting
)
enum class Setting{
    ALL,
    NONE,
    CUSTOM
}

I want to have a LEFT join between Post and UserSettings to get back Post object and settings
so I did the following inside the repository:
@Query("""
    select new com.example.dto.PostWithSettingsDTO(p, us.settings) 
    from Post p
    LEFT JOIN FETCH p.comments c
    LEFT JOIN UserSettings us
    ON p.userId = us.userId
    where up.settings= 'ALL'
""")
fun findPostsWithSettings(
    
): List<PostWithSettingsDTO>

data class PostWithSettingsDTO(
    val post: Post,
    val settings: String
)

When I did that, I got the

error: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not interpret path
expression 'us.settings'

It did work with the WHERE instead of LEFT join but I need the LEFT join.
